# Implementing class

Tags: java, class

These days I am trying to learn java. Now I just learned how to use multiple classes and I am building the game 'brick breaker', but I don't understand why this isn't working.

```
 public void run() {
    BricksandBox world = new BricksandBox();
    world.createWorld();
}
```

and here is the part of code from 'BricksandBox':

```
public void createWorld(){
        buildCanvas();
        int i = 0;
        while(i < NBRICK_ROWS){
        i++;
        createARow();
        setCollumNumber();

        }
    }
    /*builds the gamecenter */
    private void buildCanvas(){
        GRect can = new GRect(APPLICATION_WIDTH, APPLICATION_HEIGHT);
        add(can);

    }

    private void createARow(){


        for (int i = 1; i <= NBRICKS_PER_ROW; i++){
            //int y = the brickYoffset + BrickHeight+BrickSep this moves
            // the brick one down. 
            int y = BRICK_Y_OFFSET+((BRICK_SEP+BRICK_HEIGHT)*collumNumber);
            /* 
             * i-1 because it can't be set to zero. else there will be 11 bricks.
             * so you do i-1.
             */
            int x = BRICK_SEP/2+(BRICK_SEP*(i-1))+(BRICK_WIDTH*(i-1));
            GRect brick = new GRect(x,y,BRICK_WIDTH,BRICK_HEIGHT);
            brick.setFilled(true);

            //setting the color
            if(collumNumber <= 1){
                brick.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
            else if(collumNumber <= 3){
                brick.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            }
            else if(collumNumber <= 5){
                brick.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            else if(collumNumber <= 7){
                brick.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else if(collumNumber <= 9){
                brick.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
            add(brick);
            }

    }   

    private void setCollumNumber(){
        //MeeBezig. create a value that counts up from 1 to 10.
        //1 is the first row number. 2 is the second row number etc...
        int x = BRICK_SEP/2+(BRICK_SEP*collumNumber)+(BRICK_WIDTH*collumNumber/2);
        int y = BRICK_Y_OFFSET+((BRICK_HEIGHT)*collumNumber);


        if(contains(x,y)){

            collumNumber++;

            }

    }


    /** 
     * a number that counts from one to ten
     */
    private int collumNumber;'
```

First the part was just in the main file. But for decomposition I tried to put it in a diffrent class. but that now when I run the program, it just shows a blank canvas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you simplify your code to show us an example that recreates the problem that you are asking about? Try removing as much of the code as possible that doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: It's been a while since my last time using java
Don't you need a public static void main?

Comment: It looks like the createARow method creates some visual elements but never gets to place them in the root element. Shouldn't this method get some kind of initial UI context that you've initialized before, and to which it should add the rows or whatever?

Comment: @TapThatApp since something happens when the app runs (even if it's not the desired happening) it means that there is a main somewhere, probably starting a thread to which a Runnable containing the run method is passed

Comment: I am sorry, if my question is not precise enough, I am kind of a newbie on this forum. But I am going to try and explain. All this code was in the class, where 'public void run' is in. But for decomposition purposes I am trying to put it in a different class because I need to add a lot more code, to get my brickbreaker game to work. So my question is 'how can I make this class work together with the main class?'. Is this the right way to go?: public void run() {
    BricksandBox world = new BricksandBox();
    world.createWorld();